# What does "dragging something onto nationalist ground" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The politician dragging the debate onto nationalist ground is Marine Le Pen, leader of the far-right National Front (FN).

Does it mean Marine Le pen is trying to make the debate all about nationalism rather than economy or etc?

http://www.theworldin.com/edition/2017/article/12593/fight-france

Comment: The modifier "nationalist" cannot be excluded. Without it, the phrase makes no sense.... remember that "nationalists" are a group. Think  of this like a sporting field where each team has a region...

Comment: @Catija So does that mean she is trying to make the field advantageous to the nationalists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean Marine Le pen is trying to make the debate all about nationalism rather than economy or etc?

Yes, that's it exactly. "Ground" here means "territory". Debates are fought over *ideological* territory, not physical territory. The sentence is saying that Le Pen is arguing in nationalist terms - for example, "No true Frenchman would allow X".

Comment: So even when such things about economy or employment is the topic of the debate, she somehow managed to make it feel more nationalism?

Comment: @jackbang Right. Or, at least, she's trying - the original quoted sentence is in present perfect, which means the effort is ongoing (and therefore, logically, may not succeed).